# open stmp port as an attack vector?

Tags: email, penetration-test

I'm currently in the process of securing my website and searching for vulnerabilities. It has an open ftp port and an open stmp port (25). I watched a few tutorials online about hacking into stmp ports online, and realized it's incredibly easy to log into my stmp port via telnet. My question is: does this stmp port pose a security threat to my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An open port represents a program that is listening to anyone on the internet.  It provides anyone with the opportunity to attempt to exploit the program to gain access to the computer.

Allowing public access like this is *always a calculated risk*.  There are many ways to minimize the risk, such as using reputable secure software, and always keeping it up to date.  In the case of an SMTP server that you are not running on purpose, both of these precautions are unlikely.

Is there any reason at all to run the service?  Could it be all risk, no reward?